# Set values of multiple lists which are received from different sql queries in same refcursor

Tags: java, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, ref-cursor

I have a stored procedure which outputs a ref cursor.

The stored proc. contains two different queries, each of which returns a list.
Say,

```
query1 returns list of serial_numbers.
query2 returns a list of serial names.
```

How should I set these two lists in the same ref cursor variable .
Like when we retrieve this refcursor in Java I should get like

```
refCursor[0] => serial_number
refcursor[1] => serial_names
```

Each of these objects then contains the respective list.

Comment: begin 
Open ref_cursor_variable for query1;     this returns me a list of serial_numbers

Comment: You schould give more information, please add your Java code that is calling the stored procedure. Also add your stored procedure minified bodies... And clarify what you exactly want, 2 refcursor joining to one refcurser has no solution, but you can join results in a Map or something else...